# Definition of "a microservice"?

Tags: architecture, microservices

I've seen many, many references to "microservice architecture". In those discussions, they almost never refer to "a microservice", but instead call it "a service".

In interest of my company getting terminology correct, would I be correct in saying that "a microservice" is not a real thing?

Comment: I'd need to think to write a proper answer, but it's probably worth reading Martin Fowler's article on Microservices: https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html

Comment: @DarBrett Thanks. That is certainly one of my go-to articles. It doesn't call it out specifically. In almost all cases it refers to "microservice architecture".

Comment: This type of question is actually kind of hard to answer. Its quite opinionated in some ways because its a term that is thrown around quite a lot. For instance, some people have even called services "nanoservices" as being an antipattern. For what its worth, in general its a single service that carries out a domain specific behavior that is neither too small or too large.

Comment: @WillC Thanks. I'm familiar with that anti-pattern too. I do understand the definition of the service itself. Just trying to nail down terminology, as this industry tends to butcher words and turn them into something completely different. At some point in the past year I read a good article that said that calling a service "a microservice" shows a misunderstanding of microservice architectures, but I cannot find that article now.

Comment: @GaTechThomas I see what you mean; "a microservice" vs "a service". I think I was a little confused initially. I don't think there's an incorrect terminology in this sense. Its pretty much interchangeable, though one may argue otherwise. I wouldn't get fixated on this particular terminology too much.

Comment: @WillC I admittedly am a bit fixated on terminology due to past experiences. Committing to "thing x" is not the same as committing to "thing x-ish".

Answer (score 3):

I think most refer to `a microservice` as a runnable instance, an endpoint, and directly correlate it to a `Service` in SOA (an autonomous technical authority of a business capability)...

But it should just be called an endpoint and we should try and define the `business boundaries` or `Service Boundaries` in our systems or else we will end up with a distributed monolith...

Therefore I suggest that `a microservice` as you said, does not mean anything...

This [post might](https://particular.net/blog/goodbye-microservices-hello-right-sized-services) be a good read for you?

Comment: That post makes me feel more sane... Someone thinks a bit like I do. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would claim that a microservice should offer some characteristics:

- solves a single business problem in a minimal way (only solves one problem and that well)
- the operation's execution is idempotent (given the same input data the operation can be called multiple times without adverse effects to the data consistency)
- the operation is stateless (all State is provided as an input parameter). This would make the operation pure functional in developer speak
- the operation has minimal dependencies upon other operations

Comment: Thanks. I agree with those items, but I'm primarily looking for consistency on terminology.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a microservices architected system, `a service` to `a microservice` is just like `a config` is to `a configuration` - a common shortening for everyday use.

The Microservices approach is about breaking your system ("pile of code") into many small services, each typically has its own:

- Clear business-related responsibility
- Running process
- Database
- Code version control (e.g. git) repository
- API (the protocol how other services / clients will contact the Microservice)
- UI

The services themselves are kept small so as your system grow, there are more services - rather than larger services.

It worth to mention that these days (2018) the "microservices approach" is still a **buzz**. Hence, people tend to describe a system's architecture as "microservices" even if only a single aspect of it actually match the approach.

Comment: I agree with all of that except for the part about "service" being the same thing as shortended "microservice". Services existed for ages before the microservice concept came about, and many services still exist legitimately that are not microservices. Certainly in some cases the shortening is of the same thing.

Comment: I agree, and I will clarify: in the context of microservices - `services` are the same. I work with microservices for a few years now, and everyone mostly call it "services" - not "microservices".

Comment: One thing that I've been running into is that people do shorten "microservice" to "service". However, in the same ecosystem we have services that do not meet the criteria of a microservice (e.g., they are only pass-through facades and have no database).

Comment: Having said that, I'm now starting to see why "microservice architecture" makes sense: It contains a mix of pieces that cannot stand on their own - no one thing can be a microservice without the others. Seems like some disambiguation would be helpful. Something like (or better than) "class 5 microservice", which would mean "a service in a microservice architecture that meets criteria X and Z."

Answer (score 0):

The term micro-service is coined to have a clear domain defined for each of the service developed and its way beyond than a service.

A micro-service ideally works on a single responsibility and should avoid to take an extremely small responsibilities(anti nano pattern). Micro-service architecture referred as software system as a collection of independent(programming language selection, developed, deployed and scaled independently) loosely coupled services. It gives you the capability to scale horizontally on demand and can use many ways of communication among them and not have restriction over ways of communication like SOA architecture.

The responsibility of each service is to focus only on business value it creates and the other responsibilities can also be carved out using patterns like side car patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Most concise definition I have ever came across is from Sam Newman

"Microservices are small, autonomous services that work together"